# Cómo recolectar los IDs de todos los elementos de una consulta sin foreach - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo el siguiente query que me devuelve una colección que dentro tiene un array de x items

```
 $locationGroupsPlaces = $this->placeRepository->getLocationGroupPlaceByMainPlaceId($site->place->id);
```

de esto, en algunas ocasiones necesito obtener un array de los `$locationGroupPlace->site->place->id` de cada uno y lo estoy haciendo a través de un foreach para construir el array

```
$locationGroupIds = [];
            foreach ($locationGroupsPlaces as $locationGroupPlace) {
                $locationGroupIds[] = $locationGroupPlace->site->place->id;
            }
```

sin embargo, presiento que esa no es la forma más "elegante" y tampoco la más óptima, quisiera saber si es posible obtener este resultado de otra forma sin cambiar el query en cuestión.

En caso de que no sea posible y sea necesario crear otro query para obtener esto, este es el query original

```
    $mainPlace = LocationGroupPlace::where('place_id', '=', $placeId)->get();
    return LocationGroupPlace::with('place', 'site', 'site.place')
        ->where('group_id', '=', $mainPlace[0]->group_id)
        ->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();
```

qué le faltaría para que me pueda retornar directamente los `$locationGroupPlace->site->place->id` de cada uno de los `$locationGroupPlace`?

Comment: puedes hacer uso de pluck, despues del get haces ->pluck('group_id') este te retornara la collección de datos pero solo con el group_id nada mas y para accder solo necesitarias hacer, mainPlace->group_id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @Heyner Martinez, simplemente había que usar

```
$locationGroupsPlaces = $this->placeRepository->getLocationGroupPlaceByMainPlaceId($site->place->id)->pluck('place_id');
```